# is indentation working in Flex Builder on mac?

Tags: flexbuilder

is indentation working in Flex Builder on mac ?

I'm pressing APPLE + i, but my MXML code layout doesn't change. Is it maybe only for Actionscript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

⌘+I is for 'correct indentation'. This means it tries to properly indent any selected code. So this will only do something if it thinks your indentation isn't already correct. And yes, it works for MXML and Actionscript.

Use Source -> Shift Right/Shift Left if you want to change the current indentation for selected code.

Comment: I tried again, also messing up the code identation, it doesn't work. APPLE + I right ? I tried selecting and unselecting the code... moving the cursor on the same line... still nothing. thanks

Comment: Yes, i, not L.
That's very strange. FWIW, it should only work when you have code selected, and it only applies to what is selected. Maybe try the menu item and see if that works. I guess the next step would be to try a new project in a new workspace just to make sure nothing got whacked in your current one.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I just went to Preferences > General > Key and I realized there is not Apple+i command. There is Apple+j and Apple+l and all other commands but Indentation is missing. I've just installed Flex without any additional fancy stuff. So I dunno why I haven't it!